# who are you going to call?

Tags: riddle, haiku, history

> First one, now two snakes
>   Too much? Rightfully, not free
>   Alternative, less?

Comment: I can only assume the answer is going to be ghostbusters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but i think you are going to call

> The Doctor

First one, now two snakes

> Refers to the the snake and staff symbol which has been associated with healthcare. The single snake emblem is that of Aesculapius. The double snake emblem is caduceus of Hermes.

Too much? Rightfully not free ... alternatively, less?

> Probably this one talks about the high cost of healthcare facilities in some countries and need to make it more affordable

Comment: You've got the right answer. I thought the first clue would've been the hardest. There's some nuance to the other two clues based on wordplay. I'll mark yours correct in a bit if no one answers it better.